# What's the proper way to save a object with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, nhibernate

I'm new to Hibernate, I just started to do a mapping to a table, but I'm having some problems when I try to write an object, here's my unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FacilityRepositoryTest : DatabaseRepositoryTestsBase
{
    private IRepository<Facility> repository = new Repository<Facility>();

    [Test]
    public void CanGetAllFacilities()
    {
        IList<Facility> allFacilities=repository.GetAll();
        Assert.IsNotNull(allFacilities);
        foreach (Facility facility in allFacilities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(facility.NAME);
        }
    }
    [Test]
    public void CanCreateOneFacility()
    {
        try
        {
            repository.DbContext.BeginTransaction();
            Facility facility = new Facility();
            facility.FACILITY_CODE = "abc";
            facility.NAME = "Nameds";
            facility.ADDRESS = "Reinhardt strasse";
            repository.SaveOrUpdate(facility);
            repository.DbContext.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `CanCreateOneFacility`, I get this exception:

```
TestCase 'PJ1.TestUsingDevDb.PJ1Web.Data.FacilityRepositoryTest.CanCreateOneFacility'
failed: TearDown : NHibernate.TransactionException : Transaction not successfully started
--TearDown
en NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckBegun()
en NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Rollback()
```

I started debugging the test and no exception is thrown AND the data IS being recorded, but after the test is finished comes the exception.

What am I doing wrong? is this an incorrect way to save the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using S#arp Architecture, right? I believe DatabaseRepositoryTestsBase
 already provides a transaction for you, so you don't have to set one up in your test code. So try removing:

```
repository.DbContext.BeginTransaction();
```

and

```
repository.DbContext.CommitTransaction();
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Rian thank you for your answe, Yes I'm using s#arp architecture, I tried without begin and commit transaction, Now I don't get any exception, but now the object isn't being recorded. May be I'm missing something else?

Comment: What do you want to test for? I see no Assert in the test. If you want to test if facility has been made persistent, you could check if NHibernate has assigned an id, by asserting the facility.Id id not null after the call to SaveOrUpdate.